# git submodule add only pick latest Commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project that depends on other projects so I use git submodule.
But my project is only interested with latest commit, I don't want all of the commits back to the beginning.

For example [openssl zip](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/master.zip) is 6.6MB but cloning repo is 71.76MB.
I want only the 6.6MB but with advantage of git submodule.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

There is the `--depth` flag which can be passed to the submodule.
The `--depth`flag can be used in the same way as you use it when cloning repository and you wish to clone only the latest commit.

> Add the `--depth` option to the add and update commands of `git submodule`, which is then passed on to the clone command.
>   This is useful when the submodule(s) are huge and you're not really interested in anything but the latest commit.

```
git submodule add --depth 1 -- <url>
git submodule update --depth -- <url>
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/275cd184d52b5b81cb89e4ec33e540fb2ae61c1f).

Comment: Yup that is what I wanted. God bless